# Where are the errors with my ESP32 UART code

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, uart, esp-idf

I apologise for asking something like this but I have been on this issue for 3 weeks now and cannot figure it out. also i am sorry for any bad english

My project is as such: an esp32 runs a UART FreeRTOS code connected to a peripheral device. To initiate the device, you send a command that looks like "INIT10000" (in hexadecimal obviously). This initiates the peripheral, then to get some data from it you send "NEXT10006" (again in hex).

My code is here: the printf functions on lines 49 and 52 indicate a signal being sent, however I never get any recieved data.

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"

//char initBUF[] = {'I', 'N', 'I', 'T', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
char initBUF[] = {0x49, 0x4E, 0x49, 0x54, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

//char nextBUF[] = {'N', 'E', 'X', 'T', '1', '0', '0', '0', '4'};
char nextBUF[] = {0x4E, 0x45, 0x58, 0x54, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04};

static const int RX_BUF_SIZE = 1024;

#define TXD_PIN (GPIO_NUM_4)
#define RXD_PIN (GPIO_NUM_5)

void init(void) {
    const uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_EVEN,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_DEFAULT,
    };
    // We won't use a buffer for sending data.
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, RX_BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
}


static void tx_task(void *arg)
{
    const int initSize = sizeof(initBUF);
    const int NEXTSize = sizeof(nextBUF);
    int sentINIT = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, initBUF, initSize);
    printf("Sent INIT Bytes: %i ", sentINIT);
    while (1) {
        int sentNEXT = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, nextBUF, nextSize);
        printf(" Sent NEXT Bytes: %i ", sentNEXT);
        vTaskDelay(4000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

static void rx_task(void *arg)
{
    char* data = (char*) malloc(RX_BUF_SIZE+1);
    while (1) {
        const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, RX_BUF_SIZE, 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if (rxBytes > 0) {
            int pos = 0;
            while(pos <= rxBytes){
                printf("%c",data[pos]);
                vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                pos++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(data);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    init();
    xTaskCreate(rx_task, "uart_rx_task", 1024*2, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES, NULL);
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    xTaskCreate(tx_task, "uart_tx_task", 1024*2, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES-1, NULL);
}
```

One thing to note is that in the transmission, the peripheral device expects the first 4 letters as ascii, the next 4 numbers as uint32, and the last number as binary data. I am wondering if the reason I see nothing is because of this? I am sending the hex data as an array.

Any suggestions?

I have tried so many different things such as different GPIO pins, using the commented out array instead of hex.

I am expecting to see the returned packet from the peripheral, which has the same structure (letters, numbers, binary data)

Comment: The ASCII characters representing '0', '1', '4', etc. do _NOT_ have the hex values of 0x00, 0x01, and 0x04.  Rather, they are 0x30, 0x31, and 0x34.

Comment: You could try removing the peripheral from the system, connect TX and RX together, and see if you can at least loop back some data to yourself.

Comment: `0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00` is `0x00000001` in little Endian, and `0x01000000` in big Endian, when you do communication between two systems, you need to be aware of [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Most of the computer systems nowadays are storying data in  little Endian (unless you are dealing chip like Motorola MC68000 or PowerPC), but many communication protocols are transmitting data in big Endian sequence.